# Does MySQL run WHERE clause before ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql, optimization, order-by, where

I have this query:

```
SELECT my_code 
FROM ranges 
WHERE 123456789 BETWEEN first_number AND last_number 
ORDER BY type_of_code ASC LIMIT 1 ;
```

My question is, will it run the `ORDER BY` after it has selected rows from the `WHERE` clause?

I have `KEY` on `first_number` and on `last_number`. My table is around 5 million rows. I do not wish to `ORDER BY` first.

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at the query plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does.
....................

Comment: Perfect, so knowing that the where clause will maximum return 3 records does not de-perform due to the order by clause.

Answer (score 7):

The logical order in which a query is evaluated is:

- FROM / JOIN clause
- WHERE clause
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause
- ORDER BY clause

so from a logical point of view, yes the `WHERE` should be evaluated before the order by.

But the DBMS:s (in this case MySQL) is allowed to evaluate the query in any order as long as the result of the query is preserved. So in a future version it *might* evaluate a query in another evaluation order which may cause unexpected performance effects.

Now, since `ORDER BY` basically transforms the query into a cursor I think it is pretty safe to assume that the `WHERE` clause will be evaluated before the `ORDER BY` (at least as long as the table is row-based, for a column-based table the situation may be different).

Answer (score 2):

*Logically* they are in the order indicated by @Lennart.

But your query is especially hard to optimize.  There is no optimization for `WHERE constant BETWEEN col_start AND col_end`  The best the Optimizer can do is use an index on either or both columns, but then risk scanning half the table.

The Optimizer *may* use `INDEX(type_of_code)` to help with the ordering and limiting of `ORDER BY type_of_code ASC LIMIT 1`.  With luck, it will find a row matching the `WHERE` quickly; without luck, it might have to scan the entire table.

Can't win.

Have you supplied exactly the query in question?  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Also, to the ranges overlap?  (The Optimizer cannot make a useful assumption here, but you can.)  There *may* be some tricks to speed up the query, even if it has to scan the entire 5M rows.